# How do I open app from URL and put the parameter as value in a TextInput

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

Im trying to make an enrollment system for an app, where I intend on using deep linking so the users dont have to manualy type in a token in the app.

The plan is to send an email with a link like the on below:

etc: app://servertoken/lskdfnlsknfASD34fgss3633SDF

and when they click the link I want the app to navigate to a diffrent startingscreen than default and place "lskdfnlsknfASD34fgss3633SDF" in a TextInput field.

The results I got this far is when they click the link it opens the app and navigates to the default starting page.

I have tried altering the MainActivity file, without any change in result.

```
//app.js looks like this:


import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Enroll from './src/Enroll';
import Login from './src/Login';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Enroll: { screen: Enroll, path: 'servertoken/:token', },
  Login: {screen: Login }
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Login"
}
);
const prefix = 'http://servertoken/';
const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
const MainApp = () => <App uriPrefix={prefix} />;
export default MainApp;



//Enroll.js look like this:



import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

class Enrollextends React.Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Enroll',
    };

    render(){
        const token = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <Text>Enroll</Text>
                <TextInput value={token}/>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Enroll;
```

Expected result is app navigating to Home screen with token as value in the TextInput, actual result is app open to Login screen

Comment: Have you tried using navigation.getParam('token') method to extract it?

Comment: No, as i understood it this part: "path: 'servertoken/:token'" is suppose to get the param.

Comment: Instead of this line const token = this.props.navigation.state.params; try const token = this.props.navigation.getParam('token')

Comment: hi, any progress so far?